# boto3 put_object with new key python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I want to save a csv file ("test.csv") in S3 using boto3.
my bucket is "outputS3Bucket" and the key is "folder/newFolder".
I want to check if "newFolder" exists and if not to create it.

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('s3')
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket("outputS3Bucket")

result = client.list_objects(Bucket='outputS3Bucket',Prefix="folder/newFolder")

if len(result)==0:
    key = bucket.new_key("folder/newFolder")
    newKey = key + "/" + "test.csv"

client.put_object(Bucket="outputS3Bucket", Key=newKey, Body=content)
# put_object path: 's3://outputS3Bucket/folder/newFolder/test.csv'
```

I have few problems:

1. if I don't write the full key name (such as "folder/ne") and there is a "neaFo" folder instead it still says it exists.
2. key = bucket.new_key("folder/newFolder")
   AttributeError: 's3.Bucket' object has no attribute 'new_key'

Comment: Your code mentions `bucket` variable\object used as `key = bucket.new_key("folder/newFolder")`, however `bucket` is not set anywhere in your code, can you edit your question to reflect what is `bucket`?

Comment: @Eytan Avisror sorry, just added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, according to boto3 documentation, it's preferred to use the new API method - `list_objects_v2()` instead to list a bucket's objects.

I suggest using a simple boolean function to check whether a folder exist (makes your code cleaner and more readable).
for **question 1**, you can check if the prefix ends with '/' character and append it if not, - this will make sure your are looking for **EXACT** match and not *Starts With*.

Sample Function:

```
def bucket_folder_exists(client, bucket, path_prefix):
    # make path_prefix exact match and not path/to/folder*
    if list(path_prefix)[-1] is not '/':
        path_prefix += '/'

    # check if 'Contents' key exist in response dict - if it exist it indicate the folder exists, otherwise response will be None
    response = client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=path_prefix).get('Contents')

    if response:
        return True
    return False
```

Sample Implementation:

```
if bucket_folder_exists(client, 'outputS3Bucket', 'folder/newFolder'):
    pass # Do something if folder already exist
else:
    pass # Do something if folder does not exist
```

Regarding your **second question**, I added a comment - it seems your code mentions bucket variable\object used as `key = bucket.new_key("folder/newFolder")`, however `bucket` is not set anywhere in your code, -> according to the error you are getting, it looks like a `s3.Bucket` object, which doesn't have the the `new_key` attribute defined.

Comment: I added to bucket line.

Comment: Answer remains as-is, Bucket object has no new_key attribute. If you are simply passing key to other methods as a string, it should be a string in a local variable.